# Different results when constructing numpy masked array with bool vs numpy.bool_

Tags: python, numpy

When using the Python `bool` I get this result (run on jupyter):

```
data = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2], mask=False)
data,data.mask
# output
# (masked_array(data=[1, 2], mask=[False, False], fill_value=999999), array([False, False]))
```

But when I use `np.bool_` I get this result:

```
data = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2], mask=np.bool_(False))
data,data.mask
# output
# (masked_array(data=[1, 2],mask=False,fill_value=999999),False)
```

Why are the results are different?

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Because that's what you told it to do.  When the `mask` parameter is a Python scalar, it is broadcast to the size.  When it's a numpy type, that's assumed to be the ENTIRE mask.  The documentation says the `mask` should have the same shape as the data.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim. Whenever you call numpy, the python interpreter cannot use syntax sugar to make things better. You could use `mask=np.zeros(2, dtype=bool)` to be more explicit about the masking parameter. Moreover, if all your mask values are false then you could simply use `ndarrays`. It won't mask out anything.